# Where does the yeoman test-helper look for sub-generators?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm working on a custom yeoman generator, and I'm trying to add some tests for a sub-generator.

I can't figure out how to use [yeoman's test helpers](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman-test) to accomplish this.
I *have* been able to use `composeWith()` to run the sub-generator alongside my main generator, but I can't get the test helper to recognize it.

Furthermore, I'm getting some weird discrepancies when I run the generator from my test files, vs when I run it normally (from the command line).

in app/index.js:

***Note:** This code fails when run normally, and when run from my tests. If I change the `composeWith` fucntion to `this.composeWith('my-generator:sub-generator')`, it runs successfuly from the command line, but still fails during testing.*

```
initializing: function() {
  this.composeWith('sub-generator');
},
```

in my test file:

```
before(function (done) {
  helpers.run(roundhouse)
    .withGenerators([
      [helpers.createDummyGenerator(), '../sub-generator']
    ])
    .inDir(testDir)
    .withPrompts(prompts.default)
    .withOptions({"skipInstall": true})
    .on('end', done);
});
```

The error produced when running the generator from the command line (`yo my-generator`):

```
You don't seem to have a generator with the name sub-generator installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 24 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

When run from my tests:

```
Uncaught Error: You don't seem to have a generator with the name sub-generator installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 2 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

Why can't my test-file see the other generators I have installed? Instead of 24 generators, it tells me that I only have 2.

Comment: try passing the path take a look at http://yeoman.io/authoring/composability.html 
settings.local

Comment: Using `.withGenerators(['../sub-generator/index.js'])`gives the same error, but counts 1 registered generator instead of 2. I also tried passing variations on the path using `path.join()` and `path.resolve()`, to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `settings.local` when calling composeWith http://yeoman.io/authoring/composability.html

Passing the path itself will fix most of the edge case you might encounter.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! I'm still curious about why `settings.local` is needed for the tests to work, but not when running the generator with `yo my-generator`.